# creating flot chart style

Tags: php, flot

im trying to style my flot charts similar to this:

[image: chart style]

this is my current chart:
[image: current chart]

here is my chart code,

```
<?php   
include('Includes/connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="cs" lang="cs">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8"/>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="Includes/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="Includes/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="Includes/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
// Main query to pull data from 'tests' table
    $sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)*1000 AS unixDate,`date`, `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`, `test5`, `test6`, `test7`, `test8`, `test9`, `test10`, `test11`, `test12`, `test13`, `test14` FROM `tests` WHERE member_id = '1' ORDER by `date` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("no query");

//  Dataset1
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))  {
    $dataset1[] = array( $row['unixDate'], sprintf( "%.3f", $row['test1'] ));}
?>
<div id="chart1" style="width:700px;height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Chart1
    var chart1Options = {
        xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%Y-%m-%d"},

        lines: { show: true, color: "#fff" },
        points: { show: true },
        grid: {
          backgroundColor: { colors: ["#4ca8fa", "#2887da"] },
          bordercolor: "#fff",
          borderwidth: "60",
          hoverable: true }
    };

    var dataset1 = { data: <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>,};

    $.plot($("#chart1"), [ dataset1 ], chart1Options);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me out please? similar colours and also i cant seem to get hover data showing up either

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you close to the appearance you want.

HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:400px;height:300px;background-color: #6EB5F0"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),[ 
        { data: [[0,0],[1,1],[2,4],[3,3],[4,5],[5,7],[6,9],[7,10],[8,8],[9,12]], color: 'white'}
    ], {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: 'rgba(143, 198, 242, 0.7)' },
            points: { show: true}
        },
        grid: { color: 'transparent' },
        xaxis: { 
            color: 'white',
            font: { color: 'white', family: 'sans-serif', size: 11}
        },
        yaxis: { 
            color: 'white',
            font: { color: 'white', family: 'sans-serif', size: 11}
        }
    });
});
```

Result:

[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qJWSy/1/).

As far as your hover tooltips not working, there's a great example [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html).  Follow that and if you still can't get it working, update your question with **specifics** and a **minimal** code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: is it possible to limit the ticks on xaxis to only the data pulled from database? it seems to add ticks (dates) in between the values pulled via the query?

Comment: To place the ticks exactly where you want them, you'll have to specify a ticks array (https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes), as you loop your data create a second array just populated with `$row['unixDate']`.

Comment: i made a new array called Date and tried to populate but now my xaxis dissapears.

will make a new question now and mark this answered so i can show some code.